# Jasmine false positive with {} and [] in jasmine-node

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine-node

For some reason jasmine's...

```
expect({}).toEqual([]);
```

is reporting true (but they are different types). How do I do this check with jasmine?

Comment: If they are both empty, they will always return true. This is what I suppose it does. Maybe if you populate the two arrays with equal data will fix that.

Comment: That seems normal. Have a look at this : http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_equality.html

Comment: @Socialz Do you have a link to a documentation of `toEqual` supporting what you're saying ?

Comment: I just tried `expect(({}).toString()).toEqual(([]).toString())`, and it works in Chrome, but I'm not sure that it's works in all browsers.

Comment: It seems, that you need to add more context for the question. Is your task only to force Jasmine to throw alert only for `expect({}).toEqual([]);` or it's a part of more general case?

Comment: Guys this is using Jasmine-Node! So are we saying this doesn't happen in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the equality check within the `expect` clause:

```
a = {}
b = []
expect(a === b).toBeTruthy();
```

Answer (score 0):

With [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual) you can do this:

`expect( _.isEqual(a, b) ).toBe( false );`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [JasmineMatchers](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers) project.  It adds matchers like `toBeEmptyObject` and `toBeArray` and `toBeEmptyArray` and many others.